# What type of tree is this in Maryland USA?

Tags: identification, trees

I live in Columbia Maryland, between Baltimore and DC, and was curious what type of tree this is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some leaves would help.

Comment: https://www.treeguideuk.co.uk/mini-guides/bark/  Maybe you can find it in there?

Comment: Grab a magnifying lens and go here, perhaps https://woodidentification.net - or borrow R. Bruce Hoadley's **Identifying Wood** from the library.

Comment: Found it!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fQGPZTECYs

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I believe this is a beech tree.

Comment: Possibly. Bark on a beech tree of that caliper is usually completely smooth, and the heartwood is not dark like that show in the picture, A twig with buds on it would be definitive. For example: https://www.homestratosphere.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/5-bunch-of-beech-tree-trunks-Nov92021-1.jpg